# numpy.float64 error when iterating over float values

Tags: python, numpy, types

I have two 7X7 arrays (named weights and distances) where the elements are float values.
Here is the code I am working with:

```
 xmax = 7
 ymax = 7
 hist = []
 for x in range(xmax):
     for y in range(ymax):
         for i in range (weights[x,y]):
             hist = hist + [distances[x,y]]
 print hist
```

When I try to iterate in range(weights[x,y]), I get an error because of the float values in weights[x,y].  I've tried creating different frange functions to iterate over the float values, but nothing seems to be working well.  I don't know what the values of weights[x,y] will be before running the code, so I can't really put a definite start and stop in the frange function.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you expect `range(weight[x,y])` to be?  What's the purpose of this iteration loop.  You don't use `i` in the following expression.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this, but I may be wrong.  I'm using a much smaller data set for ease of example.

```
weights = [[1,2],[3,4]]
distance = [[9,8],[7,6]]
hist = []

for x in range(len(weights)):
    new_list = []
    for y in range(len(weights[x])):
        new_list.append(weights[x][y] + distance[x][y])
    hist.append(new_list)

print hist
```

There is probably a more elegant way to do this, but it should work.

Comment: That's similar to what I'm looking for, but it still isn't quite right.  I edited the original question, hopefully that'll help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

Range can only accept integers. You need to cast `int` if there is any non-integer type going in. This includes floats, strings, anything that is not an integer type. Python will not do an implicit conversion.

```
>>> range(4.)
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> range(np.float(5))
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.
>>> range(int(4.))
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

**Application to Your Code**

For your code, just do this:

```
for x in range(xmax):
     for y in range(ymax):
         for i in range(int(weights[x,y])):
             hist = hist+[distances[x,y]]
 print hist
```

Notice the explicit `int` call to ensure an integer, and not a floating point number is passed to the `range` function?

**Numpy Arange**

If you need to use non-integer values, look at [numpy.arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html).

```
>>> np.arange(5.)
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
>>> np.arange(5.5)
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
>>> np.arange(0, 5.5, 0.5)
array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5,  5. ])
```

It allows you to use floating-point numbers, custom steps, and your own start and stop. It just returns a numpy array rather than a list/iterator.

Comment: Is there a way to return a list using non-integer values?

Comment: @sunstache32, no, not using `np.arange`. The `range` solution works as long as you convert to an `int`. Although you can call `tolist()` on the numpy array. But since you can iterate over the numpy array anyway, do math on it, it would be just as good as a list anyway. Sure it's a bit slower for iteration, but that would be offset by calling `tolist` on the array anyway.

Comment: The other solution, @sunstache32, would be to increment your floating point number to a ratio using `float.as_integer_ratio()`, then iterating over the numerator range, and dividing each value by the divisor. But that's a very roundabout way to do `np.arange`.